# Static equilibrium of linkage

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, equilibrium, statics

I have a question regarding the calculation of the forces of a linkage in static equilibrium. Consider the mechanism in the figure. Points A and B can move in all 3 directions (hence they have 3 DoFs each). Now, when the linkage is in static equilibrium under the force of gravity, with each link having known mass and centre of mass, instead of drawing forces on all the links using free body diagrams, can we just assume the linkage is a rigid body (again, when in the static equilibrium), take the CoM of all the links and computer the equilibrium condition for the forces using the, global, CoM?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a rigid structure (rigid body) or a flexible structure composed of rigid rods (system of particles)?  If the former, you would be able to find the CoM independent of the forces.  If the latter, the position of the CoM would depend on the equilibrium shape. I will assume the latter as you did not show the rods welded to each other.  You have 6 unknowns ( 2 forces with 3 components) and treating it as a system of particles you can generate 6 equations from equilibrium of external forces and external moments.  However, you also have 3 unknowns for the the position of the CoM.  So other equations will be needed.

Comment: The rigid bars are connected with rotational joints, so its the latter. You are correct about the moving CoM. but the configuration of the structure is always known (its kinematics). thus you can always calculate where the CoM is. The problem is whether this simplification, of computing the CoM at each configuration and solving for the forces using that CoM, is valid, or should a force analysis be done using free body diagrams for each link?

Comment: If you know where the CoM is located you should be able to treat the whole thing  as a system of particles and ignore the individual links.  But I think it would have to be a rigid structure to be able to locate the CoM.